# In app purchase of music content for ios

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, in-app-purchase, itunes

I am writing an app for a band. It must be possible to purchase their music from within the app. Here are the options I am considering:

1) Purchase music as an in app purchase. Not very useful because AFAIK the music files cannot be exported to the ipod music library and are only playable within the app. I could kind of get around this by giving the user a URL from which they could then use to download the songs themselves but does apple block this kind of approach - is it seen to compete with the itunes music store?

2) Simply link to an album in the iTunes store. Not ideal as it takes the user out of the app. If I did go this route is it possible for the app to get a confirmation that the purchase went through or at least have the store bring my app to the foreground once finished with the purchase? Alternatively I suppose I could search the iPod library by artist from within my app to determine if they have purchased something by the band.

3) Are there any other options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linking to iTunes seems like the best step here, especially for the user, as this allows them to use the tracks across devices, and makes your life much easier when it comes to piracy limitation(links can be shared extremely easily) and also wont piss Apple off.

As for confirmation of purchase, I really have no idea, searching through the library could work I guess, but they may not have downloaded the track yet etc.

Comment: Linking to iTunes won't earn you any commission from Apple. Don't they support a mode where an app would allow users to find/purchase additional content from their various stores (iTunes, books, etc.) against some share of the extra profits?

Comment: No, there is no way of getting commission on iTunes sales, and it wouldn't make sense for Apple to offer it.

Comment: I think you are incorrect, or just outdated. There is the affiliate program. https://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/

Answer (score -1):

2.21 of App Store Review Guidelines states, that apps that simply a song should be submitted to iTunes store.